# GIS extension for Doctrine 2

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, doctrine-orm, gis

I want to write a GIS (geospatial data) extension for my Doctrine 2 project.

I know how to write simple custom functions and types. In order to accommodate the MySQL special storage format, I need to use some SQL function (GeomFromWKB() and AsBinary()) when retrieving/storing data.

I can't find a place where I tell Doctrine 2 this. As I see it, the convertToPHPValue() and convertToDatabaseValue() methods are not the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I found out so far: 
According to the IRC channel, convertToPHPValueSQL() and convertToDatabaseValueSQL() will be part of the next release, and will offer the functionality required. Once that is available, defining a CustomType is fairly straightforward.

Comment: Just updating: In Doctrine 2.1.x series these functions have been included. See here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#custom-mapping-types

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call SQL function in doctrine2 you can do it be Expression [Func](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.1/doctrine/orm/query/expr/func.html) but this will works only with DQL.

Here you have example that will tell you how to use DATE_DIFF function that is not included in doctrine.

```
$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('l');
$qb->expr()->lte(new Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Func('DATE_DIFF',array('lo.start_date', 'CURRENT_DATE()')),'0');
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a good hint for the occasional SQL that you only need once in a project.

Answer (score 0):

Update/Alternative:

I've found a symfony2 extension that serves most of my needs. I've forked it and added what I need here:

https://github.com/tvogt/doctrine2-spatial/