# Adding custom data type (geometry) in Doctrine 2.1.7. Method canRequireSQLConversion() is not called

Tags: orm, types, doctrine, doctrine-orm, geometry

I am trying to add Geometry type to Doctrine. My Doctrine DBAL version and ORM versions are 2.1.7.

I tried to follow the instructions here:
[Doctrine 2 Types - Custom Mapping Types](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#custom-mapping-types).

I successfully created the new datatype, but I have problems with convertToPHPValueSQL method. I want function ST_AsText(' .. ') to always be called when getting the geometry column from database (database is PostgreSQL 9.1 + PostGIS 2.0.0).

Doctrine DBAL 2.1 documentation says like this:

> The job of Doctrine-DBAL is to transform your type into SQL
>   declaration. You can modify the SQL declaration Doctrine will produce.
>   At first, you must to enable this feature by overriding the
>   canRequireSQLConversion method:

```php
<?php
public function canRequireSQLConversion()
{
    return true;
}
```

> Then you override the methods convertToPhpValueSQL and
>   convertToDatabaseValueSQL :

```php
<?php
public function convertToPHPValueSQL($sqlExpr, $platform)
{
    return 'MyMoneyFunction(\''.$sqlExpr.'\') ';
}

public function convertToDatabaseValueSQL($sqlExpr, AbstractPlatform $platform)
{
    return 'MyFunction('.$sqlExpr.')';
}
```

> Now we have to register this type with the Doctrine Type system and
>   hook it into the database platform:

```php
<?php
Type::addType('money', 'My\Project\Types\MoneyType');
$conn->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('MyMoney', 'money');
```

I did like this (lot of code is placeholder code, but if I did something stupid, all advice is welcome):

```php
<?php

namespace Minupeenrad\Types;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

/**
 * Class for database column "geometry".
 *
 * @author Rauni Lillemets
 */
class GeometryType extends Type {
    const GEOMETRY = 'geometry';
    const SRID = 3301;

    public function getSqlDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform) {
        return 'geometry';
    }

    //Should create WKT object from WKT string. (or leave as WKT string)
    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform) {
        return $value; //+ 
    }

    //Should create WKT string from WKT object. (or leave as WKT string)
    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform) {
        return $value; //+
    }

    public function getName() {
        return self::GEOMETRY;
    }

    public function canRequireSQLConversion() {
        return true;
    }

    //Should give WKT
    public function convertToPHPValueSQL($sqlExpr, $platform) {
        return 'ST_AsText(\''.$sqlExpr.'\') '; //+
    }

    //Should create WKB
    public function convertToDatabaseValueSQL($sqlExpr, AbstractPlatform $platform) {
        return 'ST_GeomFromText(\''.$sqlExpr.'\', '.self::SRID.')'; //+
    }
}
```

Now I added Entity that uses this column:

```php
<?php
namespace Minupeenrad\Entities;

/**
 * Field
 *
 * @author Rauni Lillemets
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="myfields.fields")
 */
class Field extends GeometryObject {
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /** 
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User") 
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @Column(type = "string", length = "40")
     */
    private $fieldNumber;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUser() {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser($user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function getFieldNumber() {
        return $this->fieldNumber;
    }

    public function setFieldNumber($fieldNumber) {
        $this->fieldNumber = $fieldNumber;
    }
}
?>
```

But if I do like this:

```php
$entity = $em->find('\Minupeenrad\Entities\Field', 1);
```

Doctrine does SQL request to database like this:

```sql
SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.fieldNumber AS fieldnumber2, t0.geometry AS geometry3, t0.user_id AS user_id4
FROM myfields.fields t0
WHERE t0.id = ?
```

Doctrine does not use my convertToPHPValueSQL method, although canRequireSQLConversion() returns true. Furthermore, I added some debug code to see if canRequireSQLConversion() is even called, and it is not called. What am I doing wrong?

PS: I tried to search Stack Overflow, but I only came up with [GIS extension for Doctrine 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367869/gis-extension-for-doctrine-2), which links to Doctrine 2.1.x manual that I already read.

EDIT: I will read here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/cookbook/advanced-field-value-conversion-using-custom-mapping-types.html

EDIT2: Fixed function getSqlDeclaration(), that was wrong in my code. Added comments.

It seems like a more complete tutorial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the answer.

In Doctrine 2.1.7, if I used $em->find(), eventually BasicEntityPersister()_getSelectColumnSQL() was called. It has following code: (taken from https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.1.x/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php)

```
/**
 * Gets the SQL snippet of a qualified column name for the given field name.
 *
 * @param string $field The field name.
 * @param ClassMetadata $class The class that declares this field. The table this class is
 * mapped to must own the column for the given field.
 * @param string $alias
 */
protected function _getSelectColumnSQL($field, ClassMetadata $class, $alias = 'r')
{
    $columnName = $class->columnNames[$field];
    $sql = $this->_getSQLTableAlias($class->name, $alias == 'r' ? '' : $alias) . '.' . $class->getQuotedColumnName($field, $this->_platform);
    $columnAlias = $this->_platform->getSQLResultCasing($columnName . $this->_sqlAliasCounter++);
    $this->_rsm->addFieldResult($alias, $columnAlias, $field);

    return "$sql AS $columnAlias";
}
```

This code obviously does not respect method "canRequireSQLConversion"

In latest Doctrine version, 2.3.1 (see https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php):

```
/**
 * Gets the SQL snippet of a qualified column name for the given field name.
 *
 * @param string $field The field name.
 * @param ClassMetadata $class The class that declares this field. The table this class is
 * mapped to must own the column for the given field.
 * @param string $alias
 */
protected function _getSelectColumnSQL($field, ClassMetadata $class, $alias = 'r')
{
    $sql = $this->_getSQLTableAlias($class->name, $alias == 'r' ? '' : $alias)
         . '.' . $this->quoteStrategy->getColumnName($field, $class, $this->_platform);
    $columnAlias = $this->getSQLColumnAlias($class->columnNames[$field]);

    $this->_rsm->addFieldResult($alias, $columnAlias, $field);

    if (isset($class->fieldMappings[$field]['requireSQLConversion'])) {
        $type = Type::getType($class->getTypeOfField($field));
        $sql = $type->convertToPHPValueSQL($sql, $this->_platform);
    }

    return $sql . ' AS ' . $columnAlias;
}
```

So the answer is to update my ORM.